# Bar missing while plotting using Matplotlib's Twinx

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization

I'm using matplotlib.axes.Axes.twinx to have a shared x-axis in matplotlib for both . I dont know why instead of 13 bars to be plotted, only 12 of them are getting plotted.

[Link of Data set](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DD8VnzwIsmL-ayaP3bEAyYyb3ZXlIokH/view?usp=sharing)
[image: Current Output]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot  as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dataFrame=pd.read_csv("NEM.csv",sep=',')
dataFrame['ratio']=dataFrame['Expert']/dataFrame['Novice']


fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 6))
ax1.set_title('N-E Analysis')
xticklabels=dataFrame['Task'].tolist()

ax1.plot('Novice', data=dataFrame, marker='', color='dodgerblue', linewidth=2,label='Novice',zorder=100)
ax1.plot('Expert', data=dataFrame, marker='', color='darkorange', linewidth=2,label='Expert',zorder=200)

plt.ylim(0,120)

ax2 = ax1.twinx()

ax2.bar('Task','ratio', data=dataFrame, color='gray',width=0.35,label='NE',zorder=0)


ax1.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax1.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax1.spines['left'].set_visible(False)

ax2.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['left'].set_visible(False)


ax1.set_xticklabels(xticklabels, rotation = 45, ha="right")
ax1.yaxis.grid()
ax1.tick_params(left='off',bottom='off')
ax2.tick_params(right='off')
plt.ylim(0,12)

h1, l1 = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()
h2, l2 = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()
p=ax1.legend(h2+h1, l2+l1, loc=2,frameon=False)


fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `plots`, it could be good practice to say explicitily how many bars or points you are going to plot. For instance, you can create an `x-axis` this way:

```
x_axis = np.arange(len(dataFrame[Task].tolist())
```

then:

```
ax1.plot(x_axis, dataFrame['Novice'].tolist(), ...)
```

after that you rename the `xticklabels` like this:

```
ax1.set_xticks(x_axis)
ax1.set_xticklabels(dataFrame[Task].tolist())
```

Do the same with the `bar` graph:

```
ax2.bar(x_axis, dataFrame['Ratio'].tolist(), ...)
```

This should do the trick.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Never use `ax.set_xticklabels` without having specified the positions as well, e.g. via `ax.set_xticks`.